# Is there an Ember.Controller method for when all views are rendered?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

For Ember.View objects, there's an `init` and `didInsertElement` method. The first is called to set up the object, the second is called once everything has been rendered and it's in the DOM.

At the controller level, I might have a few different views in my template. `init` is great for setting things up before the controller's template is rendered, but I can't figure out when the controller would know that it's template has been rendered. I'd like something like `didInsertElement` on Ember.View, but only called when all child views & the rendering template are inserted into the DOM.

Is there such a method in Ember.Controller?

Comment: There's not such thing in the controller. You can ´this.get('controller').sendAction(...)´ in the ´didInsertElement´of the view but I don't think it is a good idea. Why would you need the controller to know (and to depend) on the view(s)?

Comment: Can you provide some use case for it? Maybe there is another way to solve your issue.

Comment: are you trying to execute some code after all views have been inserted in the DOM ?, if so, you could use Ember.run.schedule, and pass the 'afterRender' queue, something like this: Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function() { //code to run, you have 'this' which you could use to get any controller you want: this.controllerFor('application') });

Comment: Here's the use case:
The controller is loading a number of views that display data. Each view is bound to an isLoading variable; when the view's corresponding isLoading is true, then it displays a spinner.

Problem is, on first page load, I'm showing 12 views with spinners. It feels disorienting. I'd like to show one big spinner that goes until all the data comes back. So in other words, I don't want to set those isLoading variables until I start requests *after* a didInsertElements-type event on the controller.

Make sense? Or is there an easier way to accomplish this display?